# In-place quicksort algorithm in Python 2

Tags: python, beginner, sorting, quick-sort

I have tried to implement an in-place quicksort Algorithm in Python 2. Please suggest how I can

1. Make the code more efficient
2. Increase readability
3. Improve writing style
4. Make it more Pythonic

```
def swap(x,y):
    return y,x


def sort(ar, start, end, l):

    if start<end-1:

        # pivot element is taken as the last element
        p = ar[end-1]

        ind=start-1

        # when a smaller no. than pivot is found, swap it with first bigger-tahn-pivot element. 
        # keep index as the recently swapped smaller integer, if no smaller number found, than index is start-1 because pivot is out as first element

        for i in xrange(start,end-1):
            if ar[i]<p:
                ind=i
                for j in xrange(0,i):
                    if ar[j]>p:
                        ind=j
                        ar[i],ar[j] = swap(ar[i],ar[j])
                        break

        #Swap pivot with the first bigger-than-pivot number            
        ar[ind+1], ar[end-1] = swap(ar[ind+1], p)

        ar = sort(ar, start, ind+1, l)
        ar = sort(ar, ind+2, end, l)

        return ar

    else:
        return ar
```

Comment: unnecessarily indenting your code is, imo, a poor decision. Instead of making a huge `if start < end - 1: pass else: pass`, I would suggest making a `if start >= end - 1: return ar` at the beginning and unindenting the rest of the body.

Comment: I would also suggest properly spacing your code: `start < end - 1` instead of `start<end-1` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `swap` function is pointless. It would be far more clear just to switch the order directly in the right hand side of every assignation.

Also, in the second `for` loop. I'm not sure you're supposed to iterate from `0`. At best it should be from `start`. Remember, the idea of quicksort is that you only modify the part of the array that corresponds to the function, `[start, end)` in this case. However, with that loop, you're now making `O(n^2)` iterations, which can be improved like this:

```
p = ar[end-1]
idx_le = start
idx_gt = end-2
while idx_le <= idx_gt:
    if ar[idx_le] <= p:
        idx_le += 1
    else:
        ar[idx_gt], ar[idx_le] = ar[idx_le], ar[idx_gt]
        idx_gt -= 1

ar[idx_le], ar[end-1] = ar[end-1], ar[idx_le]
return ar
```

The main idea is to keep track where the elements less than `p` should be placed, same with the elements greater than `p`. The new recursion should be `[start, idx_le)` `[idx_le+1, end)`.

Comment: For above code, For input: [1, 3, 9, 8, 2, 7, 5]; after completion of the first while loop, the updated array is printed: [1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 7, 9]. Which is not right. The final answer is also not sorted. I agree my code consumes unnecessary time, but your code does not seem to work. Am I missing something? Could you please check your code? Maybe post the whole function?

Comment: My apologies. You are right, when I wrote the code I didn't thoughtfully tested it. I've updated with a version that should be working and uses pretty much the same approach.